# Error trying to access my tablet from my PC

Tags: wi-fi, networking, connection-issues, file-transfer

While trying to transfer files over Wifi from my PC to my Android tablet I use the Files Manager app, which opens a server in my local network with the IP and port `http://192.168.0.5:5544`.

But when I try to put this address in any browser I get
`Error: The connection has timed out`.
What is the reason for this ?

Router: ADSL router Netgear DGN3500

Comment: Just because a port is open doesn't mean you can access it with anything, I think.

Answer (score 0):

In most cases the communication might be blocked by the firewall, on router or on the PC, confirm if `port 5544` is allowed in firewall settings.

Second check if your browser uses **proxy settings**, which allows traffic on a different port altogether (most VPN softwares usually set up proxy connections). In this case either add the **server IP** as a **local address** and allowing bypassing of proxy for local address.

Thirdly check if Network Discovery and file sharing  is enabled on both devices.

Ping and check if addresses are reachable, and set up DNS if needed.

In most cases this should resolve `connection timed out` or `not reachable errors`